# VBA Compare times correctly

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, compare, double

I am using VBA to compare two times from a spreadsheet. 
Im my example the actual value form the sheet is 23:00 in two cells. I use them for an if-statement, the values both come from two different arrays from the type Variant.

```
if dataArr(v1) = rowArr(v2) Then
```

If I debug the two values it shows the two value like this

> 0,958333333333333 / 0,958333333333333

They seem the same but the compare in the if-statement returns false

So I subtracted the two value to see if the result is zero.

```
dataArr(v1) - rowArr(v2)
```

In this case the result is not zero but

> 3,33066907387547E-16

So something is wrong with the compare or the two double values that represent the time.

The only working solution I found was to convert them to string values by

```
CStr(dataArr(v1)) = CStr(rowArr(v2))
```

which returns true as it should be.

I don't really like this solution because it is not really how it should work. I also investigated what happens to the values before they end up in the compare but I could not find any mistake . Actually all the values in the dataArr are coming from the spreadsheet (ListObject.DataBodyRange.Value) and then certain values are copied to the rowArr out of the dataArr so it really should be the same value.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: how are you loading the values in array? in your example its one dimensional , so i guess you are not reading from range to array. Show the load process.

Comment: The example is simplified because of the very complex code.

I just tested the code with the CStr and it turns out that if I add the times to the cells by hand it works. The value I work with in the first place are copied also by a sub. 

So I think the problem is the value in the cell. Even though the look the same and have the same cell format.

Comment: A double holds a precision of 17 digits but the representation is only 15. So two doubles can be different even though they look identical once converted to a string. So there's nothing wrong with the result. To compare the equality of two dates, you need to round to the precision which is 24hrs x 60min x 60 sec:  `Round(date1 * 86400) = Round(date2 * 86400)`.

Answer (score 0):

If the cells are actually formatted for time instead of a string, I would make the definition of my arrays a "Date" not a "Variant".

Then you would have all the date/time related functionality in VBA at your disposal (like DateDiff() ).

Comment: My table is for staff dispose. So there are columns with dates, times, strings and integers. I need to use it as Variant. 
But like I said above in the comments: I think the problem comes from the cell itself. When I write the time to the cell by hand it works. Just if I use the makro to write it to the cell it does not.

Comment: So, I am assuming from this information that you are storing the entire contents of the sheet in one array.
You could dimension your array as a user defined type and have a different item per column in it. Each item would have a different simple type to match up to the data type of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes floating point inaccuracies creep in.  If you want to compare then take the Absolute Value (ABS) of the subtraction and see if it is below a tolerance level, say, 1E-7 (a millionth).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Florent B I got a solution that works!

> Florent B: To compare the equality of two dates, you need to round to the precision which is 24hrs x 60min x 60 sec

So the solution is:

```
If Round(dataArr(v1) * 86400) = Round(rowArr(v2) * 86400) Then
```

It makes perfektly sense. Thanks a lot!